# editText cursor fixed position

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I am trying to make a simple calculator, but I have a problem with the editText's cursor.

My `textAlignment` is `textEnd`,the default position of the cursor is always like 0 not editText.length().

I cannot set the cursor to be at the end of the editText.length() always that cause some problem if I want to add more than number, so I put the added number to be at the exactly position of the cursor like this :

```
editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getSelectionEnd(),

 button_sbm.getText().toString()));
```

But when I want to add another number in a specified position like this :

783|345

If I want to add 1 in the cursor position it will be added but the cursor will be back at the length of 0, so I cannot add two numbers or more (123).

Any help?

Comment: do you want the cursor (and the text) to be at the right place of the edittext?

Comment: First i want the cursor will be at the end of the string in  the editText , but when the user change the position of the cursor i want the cursor to still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your `activity.xml` add on your `EditText` `android:gravity="right"` and the text will be on the right side. And the cursor will work as you want.

** EDIT **

to set your cursor at the end of the edittext write on you `onCreate` method

```
ed.setSelection(ed.getText().length());
```

where `ed` is your edittext

** EDIT 2 **

I suppose this code

```
editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(editText.getSelectionEnd(),

 button_sbm.getText().toString()));
```

is on a button click. Change it like this

```
int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
editText.setText(editText.getText().insert(pos, button_sbm.getText().toString()));
editText.setSelection(pos + 1);
```

Comment: Am already put it , and my text is on the right side , but it is a cursor problem still on left

Comment: Now with your solution if i want to add a number it will be added on the final of the string !